# HDD in RAID 1 Migration. SmartArray P410i to SmartArray P420i

Tags: raid, hp-smart-array

I have a failed HP ProLiant ML350 Gen6 server (power surge fried the motherboard). It has an embedded SmartArray P410i controller. I also have a HP ProLiant ML350P Gen8 server with an embedded SmartArray P420i controller. Question is, can i physically migrate the HDDs (two drives in RAID1) to the new server and directly boot off of it? Sort of plug and play..

Answer (score 1):

- The disks have different drive carriers and form factors. Let's assume you have 2.5" drives in both systems... you would need to move them to Gen8 disk trays or do something [*incredibly tacky*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tm4oT7zQQyY).
- The Smart Array on-disk format is the same between systems.
- You didn't mention your operating system, so it makes sense to account for the platform, hardware and driver differences. Depending on the OS running on the G6 server, support for the newer P420i may not be in place, or may require drivers.

I'd recommend seeing what you can do to get the G6 system repaired, as well as taking measures to protect the hardware from serious electrical events.

Comment: Sorry for the omission, the operating system is Windows Server 2008. What are the chances it will boot without requiring extra drivers? I do have Gen8 disk trays available that i plan to use. Im actually trying to help out a customer, Im sure a surge suppressor will be at the top of their list once this is sorted.

Comment: Yes. It will work.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your input. Im trying this out tomorrow, Ill post back my findings.

Answer (score 0):

In short, it worked! Thanks to ewwhite for the clarification. After it booted, ACU couldn't find the RAID controller plus a lot of drivers were missing. Not too bad since this was a stop gap measure, just glad no data was lost.